# how to load data from hadoop to solr using sqoop?

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, solr, hdfs, sqoop

I want to copy indexes created via MR jobs which are now residing in HDFS into solr. Is it possible using sqoop?

If yes, what is the jdbc connector or driver to use? If not sqoop, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Why would you need to copy data from HDFS (assuming that what you mean) into Solr ?, Solr is not a data store it is a search platform and typically only stores indexes and the actual data is stored else where

Comment: I am new to solr and lucene. Can I store data in lucene from hadoop?

Comment: You can theoretically, but its a real bad practice, its like mis using solr, so for any practical application you won't be using solr like that. Suggest that you read up about solr and hadoop, atleast about the use cases where each one should be used. If you have a business case at hand you might want to explain it and people could contribute

Comment: I have indexes in hadoop which I want to copy in solr and read it from there. Is that possible?

Comment: can you plz tell me how can I copy?

Comment: I would encourage you to have a look at this basic example http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/03/indexing-files-via-solr-and-java-mapreduce/

Comment: Have you had any success ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using flume. https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#flume-1-5-2-user-guide

MorphlineSolrSink: This sink is well suited for use cases that stream raw data into HDFS (via the HdfsSink) and ***simultaneously*** extract, transform and load the same data into Solr (via MorphlineSolrSink).

For more: https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#morphlinesolrsink